# How to disable spring security default sign-in / login page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am not able to make spring-security display my own login page. I have tried almost every solution available. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Below is the code and commented part in the code is which I have already tried.

SpringBoot version- 2.1.5

SecurityConfig.class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return super.userDetailsService();
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

    httpSecurity.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**","/login", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")


            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/dashboard")
                .failureUrl("/login-error")

            .and().logout().permitAll();

//////////// Tried this too /////////////////////////////////////
//        httpSecurity.cors().disable()
//                .csrf().disable()
//                .httpBasic().disable()
//                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

}
```

View Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ViewController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home"})
    public String showHome(){ return "home.html";}

    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String showLogin(){
    return "login.html";
}
```

I want spring-security to disable its own default login page and display my login page.

Comment: @Ankit Spring boot version 2.1.5

Comment: kindly try your changes with spring-boot 1.5 version. My changes on version 2.1.5 don't work either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Well, Its strange but I just created a new project, copied old project files to new one and its working as expected.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure **WebMvcConfigurer**

add the below class as your configuration and Override the method addViewControllers

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {


        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
        }

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        }
    }
```

after that allow access to your resources in security configuration

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: By adding this, won't it create confusion for fetching the view?? because I have ViewController.class which have mappings for each view. Also I don't have `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: you need to trigger your custom login page rather default spring boot login so
you can remove controller method from ViewController.

Comment: and make sure your login page is available at root path. 
Assuming your thymeleaf is available in resources/static/login.html

Comment: Adding your solution, it is still behaving the same. Also my login page is at the root path.

Comment: then your resources are not accessible.  Did you register your ResourceHandleRegistery as mention above by overriding addResourceHandlers?  And I have edit my answer as well.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to do that. I have ViewController class which automatically maps templates by matching the returned String. Resources are perfectly accessible. Problem is Spring ain't able to hide its default authentication page.